# Frame dropout cracked, what can I do? (Allied Alfa Disc / carbon)

Tags: frames, carbon, through-axle, crack

The frame thru axel hole/dropout cracked while using my wahoo kickr trainer.

1. Is this crack dangerous?
2. If it is, what can I do?

[image]

Comment: An experienced carbon frame builder might be able to glue in a new dropout.

Comment: Does the crack exist on the other side too?  It might be a deep gouge rather than a crack through.

Comment: [Rule 12](https://www.velominati.com/comment-page-8/) applies. You now have your `n+1` [trainer queen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hangar_queen).  ;-)

Comment: You can walk...

Answer (score 14):

A crack, unfortunately, is a crack. That’s dangerous no matter what the material. You could contact Allied to see if you have any options in terms of warranty. However, if you didn’t secure the bike properly, I would guess that they’d offer a discounted frame at most. You could find a carbon repair shop, e.g. Calfee and Ruckus Composites are two well known ones in the US, and there may be others local to you. From one price list I remember seeing, dropout repair was more expensive than tube repair, so I’m not sure what the most economical option is. However, that can most certainly be repaired.

Comment: If OP gets a replacement, then carbon might not be the best material for a dedicated trainer bike.  Aluminium would be absolutely fine, as would steel.

Comment: @Criggie Well, sweat doesn't corrode or rust a carbon fiber frame...

Comment: To both of you, sweat will facilitate galvanic corrosion anywhere you have aluminum inserts, e.g. cage bosses. However, I believe sweat issues could apply to steel and aluminum as well, in addition to aluminum-carbon interfaces.

Comment: @Criggie A steel frame might be the best choice. Aluminum will fatigue, especially on a trainer where the side-to-side forces are abnormally high. Light weight or whatever doesn't matter on a trainer either.

Comment: @WeiwenNg *sweat will facilitate galvanic corrosion anywhere you have aluminum inserts, e.g. cage bosses*  But those are replaceable.  When sweat corrodes away the cable stop in your aluminum frame for the internally-routed brake cable, you're stuck with doing something like running a full-length cable housing tie-wrapped to the frame.

Answer (score 8):

1. Yes it's dangerous.
2. Contact Allied.